# Reading and editing html file through c#

Tags: c#, html

i wrote a function to open an html file in c#.net like below. i have used file reader.using file reader i took all lines of a file in a string array and then saved that file as html and opened in browser.

```
            if (File.Exists("D:\\template.html"))
                {
                //...This will store all lines in an array
               string[] content = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\template.html");

                 //Read every line from file
                foreach (string line in content)
                {
                    string test = line;
                    string newtest = test.Trim();
                    if (newtest.Equals("<div id = 'divEdit'></div>"))
                    {
                     newtest =  newtest.Replace(newtest, Result);
                    }
                 File.AppendAllText("D:\\newtemplate.html", newtest); 
                }
                string path = @"D:\\newtemplate.html";
                ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();
                process.FileName = @"D:\\newtemplate.html";
                process.UseShellExecute = true;
                Process.Start(process);
                Uri uri = new Uri(path);
                WebBrowser obj = new WebBrowser();
                obj.Navigate(@"D:\newtemplate.html");
```

but the problem is the same html page/file is opening multiple times. so please suggest me the remedy asap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well.. yeah.. you're firing it off with explorer via the `Process.Start` call.. then you're also opening it in a `WebBrowser` control. Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a process with same file and you are navigating to the same file you only need to start the process or navigate to the file.